# TreeView update by user in asp web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I want my tree view to update as soon as when user adds or deletes or renames a node. This is not happening.
Here is my code for adding new node.

```
 for ( int n=0; n<ip.Length; n++)
            {
                var camip = ip[n];
                var id = user[n];
                var pa = pass[n];
                var portno = port[n];
              string camName=  fillTree.InsertCam(camip, id, pa, portno, tbSelectedClass.Text);
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode
                {
                    Text = camName,
                    Value = camip
                };
                node.PopulateOnDemand = false;

                TreeMenuView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);

            }
```

JFK.. PopulateOnDemand is false just because this new node is leaf node

If anyone could tell me what I am missing here Then It would be really helpful.

My treeview is declared in a Panel.

```
<cc1:TabContainer runat="server" CssClass="leftspace">
       <cc1:TabPanel ID="addpaneltab" runat="server" HeaderText="Add" >
           <ContentTemplate>

               <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Add Institutes" ID="AddInstitutes" OnClientClick="displayPopup(); return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
               <asp:treeView ID="TreeMenuView1"  runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeMenuView1_SelectedNodeChanged" NodeStyle-NodeSpacing="5px" CssClass="leftspace" ToolTip="Add new Details">

            </asp:treeView>
           </ContentTemplate>
       </cc1:TabPanel>
```

Should I use update panel inside tabpanel? or Am I missing some command.
When users add something under the selected node , without any refreshment or postback the recently added node should be seen right under the selected page.

I got a question on Stack overflow regarding this issue. But there was no exact solution.

Comment: Can you add the link to the other post.

Comment: @SehaxX https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837015/tree-view-update-postback